# csrutil disable "command not found"

Tags: macos

I'm trying to run "csrutil disable" from recovery mode on El Capitan and I'm getting the error "bash command command not found" when I do. I've tried setting my path as it says here to no luck Mac terminal -bash command not found?

Comment: `crsutil ...` <-> `csrutil ...`?? The proper command is `csrutil disable`

Comment: tldr? :) :) :) :)

Comment: Your headline mentions `crsutil disable` while the body contains `csrutil disable`. It's unclear if you entered the wrong command in recovery mode or just misspelled `csrutil ...` in the headline.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has pointed out, check your syntax/spelling.  [Here is much more info regarding SIP and csrutil.](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/)

Are you sure the recovery volume you used is 10.11?  If you booted from internet recovery, it will bring you to the OS that shipped with your device.

Finally, remember that any status set via csrutil will be erased upon NV clear.  There is really no 'permanent' way to set it.